# How to have stable wait for Enter/Spacebar/... in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I would like to find some stable method for asking press of *Enter*/*Spacebar*/... at the end of the loop. 
I cannot get option (1-2) work stably. 
I do not need need any GUI for the task. 
Just textual output in Matlab prompt when you can press the key. 
I have tried these options unsuccessfully but they cause my code to stagnation such that no key  do not work

```
while 1 % just indicating here a loop, not in actual code 

% Plotting here 6 Figures, and iterating/updating them in the loop 

% Option 1
% apparent docs: https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7465-getkey
while getkey ~= 13,
    disp('Enter was not pressed. Try again.'); 
end
disp('Enter was pressed.'); 

% Option 2
% Docs: https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/waitforbuttonpress.html
w = waitforbuttonpress;
if w == 0
    disp('Button click')
else
    disp('Key press')
end

end
```

Matlab: 2016a
OS: Debian 8.5 64 bit
Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA

Comment: check out the 'pause' command

Comment: Does it have to be `Enter` key?

Comment: This can easily be done if you are looking for any key other than that. Why not go with `Spacebar` ?

Comment: I removed the answer part from your question. Questions are meant to contain only the question. I judged that your addition didn't give any addition to the already accepted answer you used, so there was no point in having that in the question. If you have something substantial to add, you are free to do so in a new answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `pause` at the end of the loop.

Comment: pause alone will wait for keyboard input. You can do this:
fprintf('Enter was not pressed. Try again.\n'); and then pause;

Comment: waitforbuttonprocess will return 1 if it detects a key press. W will never be 13. 
It will either be 1 or 0. 
It will be 0 if it detects a mouse button click.

Comment: Why is `pause` better than `waitforbuttonpress`?  - - I experience that I can get the situation stable only with explicit `pause`. The so-called integral pause of `waitforbuttonpress` does not work in my situation when integrating the feature in dynamic situation. - - I think Matlab waste management has some internal issues in dynamic instances and the command `waitforbuttonpress` is not using `pause` explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

The following code will wait until <kbd>**Spacebar**</kbd> is pressed.

```
f = figure;
% The next line is just to hide the fig window away from the screen (not really necessary)
set(f, 'Position', [1e-12 1e-12 1e-12 1e-12]) 

k=0;
while ~k
    k=waitforbuttonpress;
    if ~strcmp(get(gcf,'currentcharacter'),' ');
        k=0;
    end
end
close(f)   %Closing the figure
```

Comment: Just copy paste this code at the end of your loop! The purpose of `f=figure` is that you would definitely want to close it as well with `close(f)`

Comment: @Masi  m not answerable to what Tony does

Comment: @Masi `waitforbuttonpress` does the necessary pausing. `pause` alone does not detect just the spacebar, but *any* key press

Comment: @Masi Then simply don't use the line that I used to hide the figure window. Now when you are done doing some other stuff. Click on that figure window and press `Spacebar`

Comment: @Masi I am not interested in answering that because: ***1.*** it's a new question ***2.*** you delete your comments after getting answers. ***3.*** You copy the answers of others in your question.

Comment: @Suever I found out that the `waitforbuttonpress` pause is not sufficient in many cases. It fails with > 45 GB matrices. Adding explicitly `pause(1)` solves the case.

Comment: @Masi It has nothing to do with matrix size.... Also I thought you were trying to wait for the user to hit enter. `pause(1)` only waits 1 second.

Comment: @Suever Why `pause(1)` helps then in such cases? - - Yes, I am waiting for the user hitting enter but also adding `pause(1)` before the end of the loop, see my revision below.

Answer (score -3):

My revision of Sardar_Usama's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39816935/54964). 
Edits from the accepted answer: minimum layout of the window, center position, minimum window size, and not hidden because need of doing other things while waiting for execution. 
The pause of `waitforbuttonpress` is also not sufficient in my dynamic environments; `pause` works but do not understand why

```
pause(1); % not sure; but this helps in many dynamic cases
% waitforbuttonpress pause is not sufficient

% https://stackoverflow.com/a/39816935/54964
f = figure('Name', 'Press SPACEBAR to continue', 'NumberTitle', 'off', ...
    'ToolBar', 'none', 'MenuBar', 'none', 'Units','centimeters', 'Position',[0 0 10 1]); 
movegui(f,'center');
k=0;
while ~k
    k=waitforbuttonpress; % includes pause in itself so no pause() need
    if ~strcmp(get(gcf,'currentcharacter'),' ');
        k=0;
    end
end
close(f)
```

Comment: How is this different from Sardar's answer when it comes to the essence of your question? The key is `waitbuttonpress`, I don't see anything else here. You're quoting pause, which is not present in your answer. Please explain, I'm probably missing something.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Test dynamic environments. Sardar's proposal will fail there. Adding `pause(1)` just before it solves the integration phase. Please, offer us explanation.